# How to nest a strVarName.equals around a toLowerCase in Android Java

Tags: java, android, string, function

In Android Java, I have a string variable and I want to covert it to lower case then compare it to a constant value, something like:

```
 String strBodyPart = "arm";

 if(strBodyPart.toLowerCase(strBodyPart).equals("arm"))
 {
       intBodyPartPayment = intBodyPartPayment + 60;
 }
```

Is this how I'd do this? to get the lower case value to compare to another value?

Thanks

Comment: the argument of `toLowerCase` is a `Locale` object. E.g. `strBodyPart.toLowerCase(Locale.English)`

Comment: Help me please with significance of your comment. I need to import a particular class for a Locale object? How would I code for this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two versions of the method for converting to lowercase:
  [`String.toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase())
  [`String.toLowerCase(Locale locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase(java.util.Locale))

Use the first one:

```
if (strBodyPart.toLowerCase().equals("arm"))
```

Or better yet, use [`String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)):

```
if (strBodyPart.equalsIgnoreCase("arm"))
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas,  and I assume that you recommend the second format because it is eatery to read and handles lower and upper case, just takes the "absolute value" so to speak, of the string?

Comment: I recommend the second format because the parameter can be mixed case too, and it doesn't allocate a new String for the intermediate value.